# Having trouble with function definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x

"Problem: Write a function that given two lists, returns the list of all the elements in the first list that do not occur in the second list. Your main program will allow the user to enter two lists of numbers and end input with a blank line for list 1."

I'm having some trouble resolving the problem, I have the driver code running but I just can't seem to be able to create a working function definition to go with my program. Any ideas were to start and help will be much appreciated.

This is one of many I've tried.

```
def uncommon_elements(list1, list2):

    new_list = list()
    for element in list1:
        if element not in list2:
            new_list.append(element)
    return new_list

while(True):

    list1 = input("List 1: ")
    if list1 == '': break
    list2 = input("List 2: ")
    if list2 == '': break

    new_list = list()
    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            new_list.append(i)

    for j in list2:
        if j not in list1:
            new_list.append(j)
    print(common_elements(list1,list2))
```

*Expected i/o*

```
List 1: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3

List 2: 1 1 3

[4, 2, 2]

List 1:

Process finished

My current i/o

List 1: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3

List 2: 1 1 3

['4', '2', '2']

List 1: 

Process finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost works, you just need to split the string into a list of integers, and then pass it to the function.

```
def uncommon_elements(list1, list2):

    new_list = list()
    for element in list1:
        if element not in list2:
            new_list.append(element)
    return new_list

while(True):

    list1 = input("List 1: ")
    if list1 == '': break
    list2 = input("List 2: ")
    if list2 == '': break

    #Create list of integers out of the string
    new_list1 = [int(item) for item in list1.split(' ') if item.strip() != '']
    new_list2 = [int(item) for item in list2.split(' ') if item.strip() != '']
    print(uncommon_elements(new_list1,new_list2))
```

The output looks like

```
List 1: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3
List 2: 1 1 3
[4, 2, 2]
List 1: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3
List 2: 1 1 3
[4, 2, 2]
List 1: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3
List 2: 1
[3, 4, 2, 2, 3]
List 1:
```

You can also use list comprehension to write your `uncommon_elements` function like so.

```
def uncommon_elements(list1, list2):

    return [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
```